# What happened to the algorithm at the end of the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, tenet

At the end of *Tenet*, Ives breaks the algorithm into three parts and splits them between the three of them. Again Neil gives his part back to the protagonist before joining Ives, while Ives takes away his part with him. Any reason behind why Neil didn't take his part with him? And what happened to the part of Ives and the protagonist? Were they destroyed later or hidden?

If it was so important to keep the parts of the algorithm apart and well hidden, then why they didn't destroy the algorithm. I have seen [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110704/why-didnt-the-scientist-destroy-the-formula) and other discussion sites where they say that the future generation  can go back in time and stop the destruction of algorithm. Well if that is true, then they can go back to prevent the protagonist from saving the world also, isn't it logical? Everything the protagonist do can be stopped by the future generation.

So what do they do to secure the parts of the algorithm? Is it possible to keep it safe at all?

Comment: Neil decided to go back to into the tunnel, so why would he bring a part of the algorithm back there? Also what happens to the other parts is not shown or discussed in the movie, so there's no way to know.

Comment: Ain't Ives going with Neil? He was carrying his part..

Comment: AFAIR Neil goes back alone, that's why he gives his part to Ives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pieces are continuously carried into the past by Tenet, which eventually manages to invert, separate and hide all 9 sections in nuclear storage facilities as stated by Priya during the Oslo contact, with the future antagonists recognising that the only moment they would become vulnerable would be during the collapse of the USSR. With regards to who physically takes responsibility for this we only know that Neil is not involved as he dies, only that Tenet seems to achieve this collectively with TP's guidance.

The future antagonists can attempt to chase them if they wish but as they can only travel backwards in time at the same pace time moves forward, they are safe as the antagonists will never be able to catch up with them as they continue to maintain the time separation despite the inversions.